# How to convert ISO8601 json to normal date format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting follwing json from the backend

```
creationDate:
 chronology: {id: "ISO", calendarType: "iso8601"}
 dayOfMonth: 4
 dayOfWeek: "TUESDAY"
 dayOfYear: 185
 hour: 4
 minute: 1
 month: "JULY"
 monthValue: 7
 nano: 351000000
 offset: {totalSeconds: 0, id: "Z", rules: {…}}
 second: 31
year: 2609
Uzone: {id: "UTC", rules: {…}}
```

I want to have YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm at the end.

What is the creationDate for a type? Date?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think the easiest think to use for this is MomentJS.

Comment: How about `new Date(cd.year, cd.month, ...)`? When not UTC (those `Uzone`) then go create it with `new Date(Date.UTC(...))`  and add the offset (in seconds, from  `offset.totalSeconds` field...). Is there an easier way? use moment.js which can create a `Date` using a given timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Backend should send the date in some different format, like ISO8601 or timestamp. What you posted is not ISO format, but probably java representation of `LocalDateTime`. ISO date looks like `2018-01-20T12:00:00.000+01:00`.

On the frontend side, you can then just create `new Date('2018-01-20T12:00:00.000+01:00')` as javascript supports creating dates from ISO string.

For formatting purposes you can then use `moment.js`, or some other library.